# Implicits in a Spark Scala program not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicits

I am not able to perform an implicit conversion from an RDD to a Dataframe in a Scala program although I am importing `spark.implicits._`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Main Program with the implicits:

```
object spark1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("e1").config("o1", "sv").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val data = sc.textFile("/TestDataB.txt")
    val allSplit = data.map(line => line.split(","))
    case class CC1(LAT: Double, LONG: Double)
    val allData = allSplit.map( p => CC1( p(0).trim.toDouble, p(1).trim.toDouble))
    val allDF = allData.toDF()
    // ... other code
  }

}
```

Error is as follows:

> Error:(40, 25) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[CC1]
>       val allDF = allData.toDF()

Comment: Metropolis, Thanks for the clean-up. Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the case class `CC1` **inside the main method**, you hit https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649; `toDF()` then fails to locate the appropriate implicit `TypeTag` for that class at compile time.

You can see this in this simple example:

```
case class Out()

object TestImplicits {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    case class In()
    val typeTagOut = implicitly[TypeTag[Out]] // compiles
    val typeTagIn = implicitly[TypeTag[In]]   // does not compile: Error:(23, 31) No TypeTag available for In
  }

}
```

Spark's relevant implicit conversion has this type parameter: `[T <: Product : TypeTag]` (see `newProductEncoder` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits)), which means an implicit `TypeTag[CC1]` is required.

To fix this - simply move the definition of `CC1` out of the method, or out of object entirely:

```
case class CC1(LAT: Double, LONG: Double)

object spark1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("e1").config("o1", "sv").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/TestDataB.txt")
    val allSplit = data.map(line => line.split(","))

    val allData = allSplit.map( p => CC1( p(0).trim.toDouble, p(1).trim.toDouble))
    val allDF = allData.toDF()
    // ... other code
  }

}
```

Comment: Note: edited my answer (the first version had the right fix but the wrong explanation)

Comment: Tzach, Makes sense. Thanks for the help, Marc

Comment: @TzachZohar, @user1154422, the whole idea about creating `CC1` "_class dynamically (at run time, not compile time)_" is obviously **_wrong_**. You can validate it by commenting out the bad line of code and looking into compiled `.class` files. Also you don't have to move the class `CC1` to top outer context, it is enough to just move it outside of the local compilation context i.e. directly inside `spark1` object. This seems to be related to [SI-6649](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649) where similar behavior is described as intentional (although I don't get the reason for it).

Answer (score 0):

I thought the `toDF` is in `sqlContext.implicits._` so you need to import that not `spark.implicits._`. At least that is the case in spark 1.6